# Flutter Firebase field does not exist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my data from Firebase, some users may have a certain field and other may not. How do I do it so that if a particular field exists it should display it, else it should just pass SizedBox?

```
StreamBuilder(
stream: db.collection("User").snapshots,
builder: (context, snapshot){
      final time = snapshot.data?["Time"];
    return Text(time) /* if this user has the field "Time" in his docs, it should be displayed, else 
                       return nothing*/
}

)
```

Comment: maybe snapshot.hasData check would do

Comment: I meant that there a lot of fields. However, some users may have a particular field and others may not. so if that particular field does not exist for a user, just do nothing or just place a SizedBox() there

Comment: A Flutter `StreamBuilder.build` implementation has to return a `Widget`. It can't return "nothing": https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder/build.html

Comment: final time = snapshot.data?["Time"];   if(time == null) SizedBox();// try null check

Comment: @JB Jason Yes, I did that but it's still telling me field does not exist

Comment: Shouldn't you get the data with snapshot.data()?["Time"] ? The data will be a Map, so like @JBJason said, you should null check it and return your widget

Comment: Thanks but I've figured it out already

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("User").snapshots,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data?.docs[0].data().containsKey("time")) {
      // return your widget
    } else {
      // return sizedbox
    }
  },
)
```

Comment: Thanks but I've figured it out already